# Get ALL string properties nested within Wrapper class C#

Tags: c#, linq, system.reflection

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to dynamically traverse an object hierarchy to find ALL string properties under a parent class and do a replace on those strings.

Let's say I have a parent "wrapper" class with some properties. Like so

```
public class ParentWrapper
{
    public Person Mom { get; set; }
    public Person Dad { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> Children { get; set; }
    public Person FavoritePerson { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to dynamically use reflection to find ALL string properties that are inside ParentWrapper or any other object. I want to find the string property "FamilyName" that is in the parent class, but I also want to find all of the string values inside the nested classes. I would want to find all the strings for FirstName and LastName for each person and any strings inside objects nested in child classes.

```
.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
```

This would get me all of the string properties inside the ParentWrapper class but I want to be able to dynamically drill down to all the different levels.

Hopefully, my request makes sense.

Comment: Do you know how to write a recursive method in C#?

Comment: Yes, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: Then write a recursive method that enumerates the properties of an object, and for each property either 1) adds it to a list of string properties 2) ignores it or 3) invokes itself recursively with the Property's value.

Comment: What do you want to do with `string[]` (string array) members?

Comment: Do you want to find the values of the properties, or do you want to find the `MemberInfo` for the fields or properties? How do you want to differentiate e.g. the `FirstName` for `Dad` from the `FirstName` for `Mom`?

Comment: Or how do you want to handle `Children`?

Comment: I actually want to do a find and replace on these strings, so I really need to work with a reference to the original object to update the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not check it right now but i think u could do somethin recursive here like:

```
private static void ReadPropertiesRecursive(Type type)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                var FamilyName = property.GetValue(property))// something like this
                //do what u want with searched values
            }
            if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                ReadPropertiesRecursive(property.PropertyType);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to pass an object instance, not a Type.

Comment: Thanks so much, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft and F3cro. You were very helpful.